# Realm: How to temporarily store objects in Realm without persisting it?

Tags: realm, swift2

I want to store temporarily some Objects in to realm without persisting it for the next launch.
In the realm documents I see that it says for updating and adding you have to use inside a write transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use in-memory Realm and multiple Realms in the app. So you use in-memory Realm for the objects that you do not want to persist. Otherwise, use normal Realm for the objects should be persisted.

```
let realm = Realm(inMemoryIdentifier: "MyInMemoryRealm")
```

Please see also https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#in-memory-realms for more details.